# Alternative proof of isomorphism between linearly ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The following theorem theorem is proved in Hrbacek and Jech's Introduction to Set Theory:

> **Theorem:** Let $(A, \prec)$ be a nonempty linearly ordered set with the properties:
>
> - **(a)** For every $p \in A$, there is $q \in A$ such that $q \succ p$.
> - **(b)** Every nonempty subset of a has a least element (in the order    $\prec$).
> - **(c)** Every nonempty subset of $A$ that has an upper bound    has a greatest element (in the order $\prec$).
>
> Then $(A, \prec)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N}, <)$.

We need to show there is a biyection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ that preserves order. My questions (**below**), specifically, are about the part where they prove their function is surjective. So i'm gonna sketch the first part of the proof and then will reproduce verbatim the argument I am referring to:

Sketch of proof: A sequence $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ is constructed recusrively as follows:

- **(i)** $f_0 = a =$ the least element of $A$ (it exists by (b))
- **(ii)** $f_{n+1} =$ the least element of $A$ greater than $f_n$. (it exists by (a) and (b))

Clearly $f_n \prec f_{n+1}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $f_m \prec f_n$ whenever $m < n$ (by induction) and $f$ is one to one.

We now prove the range of $f$ is $A$. Their argument is this:

> If not, $A - \operatorname{ran}{f} \neq \emptyset$; let $p$ be the
> least element of $A - \operatorname{ran}{f}$. The set $B = \{q \in A: q \prec p \}$
> has an upper bound $p$, and is nonempty (otherwise, $p$
> would be the least element of $A$, but then $p = f_0$). Let $q$ be the
> greatest element of $B$ (it exists by (c)). **Since $q \prec p$, we have
> $q = f_m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$**. However, it is now easily seen
> that $p$ is the least element of $A$ greater than $q$. Therefore, $p = f_{m+1}$
> by the recursive condition (ii). Consequently, $p \in \operatorname{ran}{f}$, a contradiction.

**Question 1:** is the boldfaced line the only part where they use the fact $p$ is the least element of $A - \operatorname{ran}{f}$? It seems to me it is.

**Question 2:** Is the following alternative "proof" of this fact correct?

**Proof:** Take $p \in A$ (notice I do not assume $p$ is a least element) and define $B = \{f_n \in A: f_n \prec p\}$. If $p = a = f_0$ then we are done, so suppose $a = f_0 \prec p$; hence $B \neq \emptyset$ since $f_0 \in B$. Also, $B$ has $p$ as an upper bound so it has a greatest element $f_n$.

- If $f_{n+1} \prec p$, then $f_{n+1} \in B$ and $f_n \prec f_{n+1}$, which is impossible since $f_n$ is the greatest element of $B$.
- If $p \prec f_{n+1}$, then $f_n \prec p \prec f_{n+1}$ and $f_{n+1}$ is not the least element of $A$ greater than $f_n$.

We conclude then that $f_{n+1} = p$ (we are using the fact $\prec$ is a linear order here) and $p \in \operatorname{ran}{f}$.

Comment: For the first question, we need $p=\min(A\setminus\operatorname{ran}f)$ to ensure $p$ is the least element greater than $q$. I think no other part of the proof uses this fact any further.
For the second question, your proof looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since $q \prec p=\min(A\setminus \operatorname{ran}(f))$ it implies that $q \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ or else the minimum would be $\prec$ than itself.
(or quite formally, if $q \prec p$ then $q$ cannot be in $A \setminus \operatorname{ran}(f)$, so $q \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ and $q=f_n$ for some $n$ etc.).

Why do you need an alternative argument for that? It only complicates matters.

And if $p = \max B \prec q$ we also see that there can be no $r \in A$ with $p \prec r \prec q$, as $p$ is already the max of $B$ and $r$ would have been in $B$ too (being $\prec q$). So that exactly tells us that $q = \min\{r \in A \mid r \succ p\}$ (here we use that the order is linear) which equals *by construction* $f_{n+1}$ if $p=f_n$. So $q \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ after all, a contradiction.